# Adding new item to an array of structs in C

Tags: c

I have some structs as following:

```
typedef struct {
    char debutAge[15];
    char finAge[15];
} Age;

typedef struct {
    char type[15];
    char composants[50];
    Age utilisation;
} Categorie;

typedef struct {
    int code;
    char nom[30];
    float prix;
    Categorie med;
    int quantitie;
} Medicament;

#define MAX 100
typedef Medicament Pharmacie[MAX];
Pharmacie P;
int nb=0;
```

In my main function, I'm trying to add a new element to the `Pharmacie P` array, this is what I tried:

```
void main() 
{  
    Medicament m = Saisir(); 
    ajouterMedicament(P, nb, m);
    afficherMedicaments();
}

int ajouterMedicament(Pharmacie *ph, int *nb, Medicament m) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < *nb; i++) {
        if (m.code == ph[i].code) {
            ph[i].prix = m.prix;
            ph[i].quantitie = m.quantitie;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    
    if (*nb < MAX) {
        ph[*nb] = m;
        *nb += 1;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I'm getting an error on this line: `mif (m.code == ph[i].code) {` :

```
expression must have struct or union type
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: `P` is a `Pharmacie`, but the function expects the first argument to be `Pharmacie*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to declare the first argument as `Pharmacie *`. `Pharmacie` is a typedef for an array, so you don't need to add `*`.

```
int ajouterMedicament(Pharmacie ph, int *nb, Medicament m) {
```

And in the call, you need to pass a pointer to `nb` so it can be updated:

```
ajouterMedicament(P, &nb, m);
```

In general it gets confusing when you use `typedef` for pointer types, and you ran into that. I recommend not doing that.  See [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers)